# Is MariaDB required with Craft CMS or can MySQL be used?

Tags: mysql

I am currently installing Craft CMS on a test server, The server runs other development services. Currently installed on the server is MySQL 14.4.
Is Mariadb are requirement or can I utilise MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Both MySQL and Mariadb are fine to use https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/requirements.html#required-php-extensions